# How to save command, to save it in batch file?

Tags: batch-file, save, echo

`@echo @echo *command* >> text.txt >> text.bat`

File `text.bat` is created, however in `text.bat` is only `@echo *command*` not `@echo *command* >> text.txt`

`@echo "@echo *command* >> text.txt" >> text.bat` will result to have `"@echo *command* >> text.txt"` (with ", but windows command line can't process command like "echo blabla")

Any walk around or fix?

Comment: You know that the > symbol is a special character because it redirects a file stream to a file.  So if you need to use that character literally, then you need to escape that character from doing its normal programming feature.  You can escape characters in batch file by preceding a character with a ^.

Comment: Thanks! It helped!

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the redirection characters, *(and in the case of the version below,  the first closing parenthesis)*, e.g.

```bat
@(Echo @(Echo *command*^)^>^>"text.txt")>>"text.bat"
```